# Why is a field in a Django sqlite database converted from decimal to integer outside of the app?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

> A `Decimal` field defined in a model form behaves as an `integer` outside of Django; the field remains a `Decimal` from within the Django application.  Why would this happen and how can I force the field to remain a `Decimal` in all use cases?

**Background:**

Using a `model form`, I've set the data type for two fields (`low` and `medium`) in a database to a decimal as follows:

```
class Limit(models.Model):
   test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
   low = models.DecimalField('Low',    max_digits=19, decimal_places=10, blank = True, default =None, null = True)
   med = models.DecimalField('Medium', max_digits=19, decimal_places=10, blank = True, default =None, null = True)
```

The values of the fields entered into the form are:

```
low     med
135     2.3
7.7     13.2
1.98    3.4
0.84    2.9
0.132   2.2
0.9     2.8 
1       4.1
5       3.4
0.47    5.3
27      4.3
```

When used within a Django application, the fields `low` and `med` behave as Decimals.

In the manage.py shell:

```
lims = Limit.objects.filter(low__isnull=False)

for item in lims:
    print type(item.low)

<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
...
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

In the app itself, values also show decimal places and behave as Decimals.

**Problem:**

Outside the app the `low` values are integers, while the `med` values remains decimals:

These values are from DbVisualizer, but the same is pulled in R via `dbConnect(SQLite()...`.

```
135 2.3
0   3.4
0   2.8
5   3.4
1   4.1
0   5.3
0   2.9
0   2.2
0   13.2
27  4.3
```

Using DBVisualizer it appears that the `low` field type is a defacto integer and a JDBC: BIGINT;  the field `med` is a float and a JDBC: DOUBLE.

**Attempts to solve the problem:**

So far, I've rebooted a few times, reconnected and disconnected to the database, tried to make small changes to the problem table and migrated it, and entered all decimal values as data.

**Additional Information:**

The app is built with Django 1.7.1, currently in a development environment on a mac pro (OS X 10.9.5).

Nothing too custom about the database, here is the settings.py line:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db2.sqlite3'),
   }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the value of the `low` field also `0` in most cases if you load the data from the database in Django? If so, your migrations are probably messed up in some way, preventing Django from converting the column to the proper column type, and some data is lost upon saving.

Comment: @knbk: In Django, the values are exactly as entered, displaying 0-3 decimal places faithfully.  I'll take a look at rolling back the migration or rebuilding from scratch.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Despite rebuilding the database the integer autoconversion anomaly remains.  As an interim solution I changed the field to a `float`, which does retain the decimal places.

```
class Limit(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    low = models.FloatField('Low', blank = True, default =None, null = True)
    med = models.DecimalField('Medium', max_digits=19, decimal_places=10, blank = True, default =None, null = True)
```

Query in DBVisualizer:

```
135.0    2.3
1.98     3.4
0.9      2.8
5.0      3.4
1.0      4.1
0.47     5.3
0.84     2.9
0.132    2.2
7.7     13.2
27.0     4.3
```

Now I simply need to be careful with any equality comparisons using that float...

I still welcome any permanent solutions to fixing this apparent bug.